# How could we recover Component info in alternative way of PageMeta that always comes null?

Tags: sdl-tridion, sites-9.5, componentpresentation

We need to recover Component Info (schema id or component Template id) in order to know how to apply a condition with this info.

Via PageMeta we could observe that always component presentation meta comes null.

[image: Definition of fields in PageMetaImpl, "this.componentPresentationMetas = null"]

[image: Info that we need to recover "getTemplateId()"]

So we need if we have another alternative to recover this info of a component embedded in a page or there are another function that be able to do that.

Any advice for this?

Comment: Can you give some context? What kind of project is this?

Comment: The way the question is posed it is quite hard to understand what you're trying to do, and where... can you add more info please?

Comment: How can recover component information via PageInfo if SDL give us only null info about component presentation? Are another function related with the page that could give us these information?